# PHP Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/

Tags: php, laravel-5, github, composer-php

I cloned new project from github which has following dependencies:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "backpack/base": "^0.7.16",
    "backpack/crud": "^3.2",
    "backpack/permissionmanager": "^2.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.9.2",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/passport": "^2.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "league/fractal": "^0.16.0"
},
```

When I am running composer update or any other command, it shows the error as follows:

`PHP Fatal error:  Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 85`

`Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 85`

I am currently using PHP 5.6. What could be the problem?

Comment: your php version is probably the problem... [scalar type hints](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) (scalar variables are those containing an `integer`, `float`, `string` or `boolean`) are only supported since `PHP 7`. e.g. if you run code on older PHP versions, it expects a string class, i.e. it does not allow a string (scalar) default value.

Comment: Since it reports an error in `/usr/share/php/...` I guess the issue is not in your cloned repo. Is this path listed in your `include_path`? It clearly says the default value of a CLASS type hint can only be `null`. `function myFunction(SomeClass $parameter = null) {}`. Please add the file and line in question to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Your Composer Version is not working with php 5.6

To bring it to work, use it as composer.phar

See https://getcomposer.org/download/

Download Composer Latest: v2.0.9

To quickly install Composer in the current directory, run the following script in your terminal. To automate the installation, use the guide on installing Composer programmatically.

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Comment: Composer supports PHP 5.3, it should work on PHP 5.6 without any trouble.

Comment: @rob006
I had the same Error, installing composer global with php7.2
Downgrading to 5.6, get the Error from Composer because Composer uses Symfony CLI, see message. 

PHP Fatal error:  Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 85

Create a composer.phar like described with php5.6 and the Error was gone.

Thanks for downvoting, maybe test the setting.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the composer (which was installed when I was using PHP7) and installed it again. It is solved my problem.

Ubuntu 20.04, PHP5.6

1. type composer
2. sudo rm -r /usr/local/bin/composer (or sudo apt remove composer)
3. sudo rm -r ~/.cache/composer
4. sudo rm -r ~/.local/share/composer
5. sudo rm -r ~/.config/composer
6. sudo apt install curl php5.6-cli
7. curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, although I'd try `sudo apt remove composer` before digging in with `rm -r`.  What's the purpose of running `type composer`?

Comment: bash: /usr/bin/composer: No such file or directory, i got error